# Sigma notation properly type set

Tags: typography

I want to typeset the sum from 1 to n of j. So I want to generate a sigma with 1 under and n over and follow that with j.
I need a plugin to Word or Word Pad that acts thus. I type my regular text until I come to "sum from 1 to n of j". At trhis point I go to my palette, click on the icon of a sigma with loer and upper values, then type 1 thn type n and then type j. As I do I get in succession
sigma - sigma with 1 under - sigma with 1 undr and n over - sigma with 1 undr and n over followed by j

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Your question is a bit confused: it’s not clear whether you are using Word or Word Pad to edit your LaTeX sources, and want a tool to enter the notation `\sum_{j=1}^{n}` via a menu (ugh!), or you are typing math directly in Word or Word Pad.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with TeX/LaTeX but is rather asking how to use a certain plugin for MS Word.  I'm voting to close as off-topic.